# Trigger Modal from ajaxContent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a live search on a webpage (CodeIgniter, jQuery and Bootstrap are being used).
Basically it works as this:

1. On input it triggers an AJAX-request
2. It makes a request to a file which returns a JSON-object
3. On successful request it parses the object
4. All content is parsed into table rows

One of the table cells contains a button. 
The button should open a Modal window, by javascript. 
Why by JS? Because it should first do another AJAX-request to fill the Modal content.

However, it doesn't work. It works on a button that is already on the page in the beginning. But I can't get the JS to be triggered on AJAX-content.

Ideally, I would like to see it trigger a .click() event, when the button is clicked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you put your relevant code here?

Comment: It seems that the best way to solve an issue is, after a long time online research, to post it on Stack Overflow. Five hits later, the solution appears on Google…
I found this: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/live-is-deprecated-but-on-doesn-t-work-on-not-existent-markup.

I replaced $('.loopje').click(function(){ .. }); by $('#existing_parent_element').on('click', '.loopje', function(){ .. });

Comment: You can trigger the click event on the success callback of the ajax request too but the answer below is the best I presume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click event binds the event to dom elements which are already available.

If you dynamically add an element to your page, those will not have the events you had bind.

Instead you need to attach event handler to your button. You can do it via [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function of jQuery.

```
$(document).on('click', '#newButtonID', function() {
   // Your second ajax call goes here
});
```